# How to select the last cell of a table in a QTextEdit (QTextBrowser)?

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qtextbrowser, qtextcursor

I am trying to select a part of a table with text that is in a QTextBrowser (QTextEdit acts the same in this matter).
I've made the table using html tags and seting append();

I can select all the text with:

```
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
//    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfLine, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);  //does not work
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
cursor.select(QTextCursor::Document);
```

But I cannot select one cell (or even one row).
I've tried QTextCursor::NextCell and QTextCursor::NextRow as there is written in the Qt reference manual.

I've managed to select the whole row with:

```
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::PreviousBlock, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextBlock, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
cursor.select(QTextCursor::BlockUnderCursor);
```

I am still unable to select only one cell.
I've tried moving one cell in a row and then using cursor.selectedText(); but with no succes.

Comment: I think using `QItemSelectionModel::select()` function might help.

Comment: @vahancho Could You give me some more details on how to use QItemSelectModel on a QTextBrowser?
I thought its only for the model/view framework.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood you. I thought it's about a table view, as you mentioned table and cells.